# Php what is the name of this and what does it do?

Tags: php

I'd love to know what this means so I can google it as I see it all the time and it seems to be very useful

```
(($winstate==1)?'X':'O')
```

edit: The vars are irrelevant.

Thanks guys

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's called a [ternary operator](http://php.net/ternary), it's PHP's only ternary operator, and it's shorthand for a conditional:

```
if($winstate == 1){
    return 'X';
}else{
    return 'O';
}
```

It's frequently used when the conditional test results in an assignment or returns something, in this case suppose you wanted to assign 'X' or 'O' to a variable `$move`, it's far more concise to write:

```
$move = ($winstate == 1) ? 'X' : 'O';
```

Comment: A `ternary operator` is an operator that takes three arguments. The `conditional operator` in PHP is **a** `ternary operator`. In PHP it happens to be the only `ternary operator`, but that doesn't mean it's **the** only one in the universe. The universe is big.

Comment: @Peter: that's fairly pedantic considering on a quick Google search I can't find a single ternary operator that *isn't* a conditional operator. Also note that PHP's manual refers to this as **the** ternary operator numerous times.

Comment: @Mark - It's pedantic because the question asked what the name of the operator was and the answer is a description of the operator. Also the OP wants to google the operator. They'll find different results looking for `ternary operator` vs `conditional operator`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Comparsion Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

There's everything explained

```
<?php
// Example usage for: Ternary Operator
$action = (empty($_POST['action'])) ? 'default' : $_POST['action'];

// The above is identical to this if/else statement
if (empty($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = 'default';
} else {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
}

?>
```

Comment: One more question. How does the array help get the fields inside winning... 
    $value=array('-1','-1','-1','-1','-1','1','0','-1','1');
    $winning_sequences = '012345678036147258048642';
    $player = $value[$winning_sequences[0]];
Generally confused. Any links would be great! Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: @Matt: this returns first (0 is first) character in $winning_sequences .

Comment: but why does it need the array?

Comment: @Matt: open new question for it. And please at least upvote my answer